# How can I get the required data?

Tags: swift, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database

```
    ref = Database.database().reference()

    let currentUserID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid

    let userRef = ref.child("users").child(currentUserID!)

    let userRefQuery = userRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "requests").queryEqual(toValue: "received")

    userRefQuery.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

        if (snapshot.value is NSNull) {

            print("no data found")
            return
        }

        print("value:")
        print(snapshot.value)

        print("key:")
        print(snapshot.key)

    })
```

[Firebase Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K8mIn.png)

How can I get the userIDs of users under "requests" which has a value of "received". Because it might also be "sent". Currently, I am not getting any data!

Comment: You're going to need to post your Firebase database as a screenshot.

Comment: Hey @MattHarris! I have edited my post. You can have a look at my firebase database now.

Comment: add print(snapshot) before if and see what is the ouput?

Comment: Hey @3stud1ant3! I am getting the userID of the current user

Comment: replace .value with .childAdded and see what is the output of print(snapshot)

Comment: Getting nothing!

Comment: Remove .queryEqual(toValue: "received") and see what is the output?Are we getting the right requests?

Comment: With .value, I am getting just the email of the current user. And with .childAdded, I am getting whole database of current user, that is current user's email, name, requests, and uID

Comment: Can you show the output in case of .childAdded?

Comment: Hey! I got the desired result. Not by querying though! you can see my edit section under my question

Comment: Good work, I think instead of edit, you should post it as an answer, that will be more helpful to other

Comment: check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36729247/retrieving-data-using-firebase-swift/36729395#36729395

Answer (score 0):

This is how I got it worked:

```
ref = Database.database().reference()

let currentUserID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid

refHandle = ref.child("users").child(currentUserID!).observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in

    print(snapshot)

    if let userDict = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] {

        if let requests = userDict["requests"] as? [String: String] {

            print(requests)

            for request in requests {

                if request.value == "sent" {

                    self.userIDs.append(request.key)
                    print(request.key)

                }

            }

        }


    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the question that you deleted, instead of:

`char temp = s[start]`

do

`char temp = s[i];`

Comment: Yes, but that would skip all whitespaces. And I don't want that. I just want to skip the whitespace at the starting of a new line. Anyways, thanks a lot

Comment: char temp = s[i] + ' '; will add whitespace. if you also remove the cout << "\n" line it will put your string in one line and there will be whitespaces between the words. if your looking to get something different and still need help feel free to let me know what results your trying to get

Comment: I was looking for something different but not got it. Thank a lot anyways!